# Why does this branch break type inference?

Tags: java, type-inference

I'm using a home-grown implementation of `Either` in Java, which has a methods like this:

```
public static <L, R> Either<L, R> left(final L value);

public static <L, R> Either<L, R> right(final R value);

public <T> T fold(
        final Function<? super L, ? extends T> leftFunction,
        final Function<? super R, ? extends T> rightFunction);
```

These two methods compile and work fine:

```
Either<Foo, Bar> rightToLeft() {
    Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
    return input.fold(
        l -> null, 
        r -> Either.left(new Foo())
    );
}

Either<Foo, Bar> rightToRight() {
    Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
    return input.fold(
        l -> null,
        r -> Either.right(new Bar())
    );
}
```

This method does not compile:

```
Either<Foo, Bar> rightToLeftOrRightConditionally() {
    Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
    return input.fold(
        l -> null, 
        r -> {
            if (r.equals("x")) {
               return Either.left(new Foo());
            }
            return Either.right(new Bar());
        });
}
```

Error:

```
incompatible types: inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)
    inferred: Either<? extends Object,? extends Object>
    upper bound(s): Either<Foo,Bar>,java.lang.Object
```

(I've trimmed out the package qualifiers to make the error more readable)

I can make it compile by specifying the types:

```
if (r.equals("x")) {
    return Either.<Foo, Bar> left(new Foo());
}
return Either.<Foo, Bar> right(new Bar());
```

But why do I need to? And how can I avoid this code clutter?

Comment: because the compiler gets confused? You should post code for `left` and `right`

Comment: @RC. I've added signatures of `left()` and `right()`

Comment: Can not reproduce. This compiles fine for me, in both `javac` and eclipse.

Comment: @JornVernee thanks for looking. See my response to Dmitri below -- what version of `javac` did you use?

Comment: @Slim I'm using `javac 1.8.0_101`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work.

It compiles on the latest JDK, 1.8.0_121.

It fails to compile on JDK 1.8.0-51.

This means it's most likely a bug in this version of the JDK, since later versions should not change the behaviour of the compiler unless to fix a bug. It may be bug [JDK-8055963](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055963).

So, the solutions are:

1. Upgrade your compiler
2. If you can't upgrade the compiler (e.g. someone else, stubborn, owns the build system), stick with your existing workaround of making the types explicit.

Answer (score 1):

I do not see your entire class but this code compiles for me:

```
class Foo{}
class Bar{}

class Either<L,R> {

    private L left;
    private R right;

    public Either(L left, R right) {
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L,R> left(L l) {
        return new Either<>(l, null);
    }

    public static <L, R> Either<L,R> right(R r) {
        return new Either<>(null, r);
    }


    public <T> T fold(
            final Function<? super L, ? extends T> leftFunction,
            final Function<? super R, ? extends T> rightFunction) {
        return null;
    }

    Either<Foo, Bar> rightToLeft() {
        Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
        return input.fold(
                l -> null,
                r -> Either.left(new Foo())
        );
    }

    Either<Foo, Bar> rightToRight() {
        Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
        return input.fold(
                l -> null,
                r -> Either.right(new Bar())
        );
    }

    Either<Foo, Bar> rightToLeftOrRightConditionally() {
        Either<Foo, Bar> input = Either.right(new Bar());
        return input.fold(l -> null, r -> {
            if (r.equals("x")) {
                return Either.left(new Foo());
            }
            return Either.right(new Bar());
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: I copy/pasted this into `test.java`, added `import java.util.function.Function` to your version, ran `javac test.java` and got `inferred type does not conform to upper bound(s)`. Javac version `javac 1.8.0_51`.

Comment: Hah! Compiles in JDK 1.8.0_121 but not in JDK 1.8.0_51 -- wonder which bugfix is responsible.

Comment: I was thinking about differences between Java versions (7 vs 8) but it was fixed inside Java 8 releases. Interesting.

Comment: Do you think it's this: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8055963 ?