# What does var<T> do in Java?

Tags: java, generics, var, ecj

A friend of mine noticed that

```java
var<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Double>();
```

was valid in Java. It turns out that the type of `list` is evaluated to `ArrayList<Double>`.

When using `var<Integer> list = new ArrayList<>();`, `list` is just `ArrayList<Object>`.

Both of us were not able to figure out, what the generic type of `var` does, as it seems to be ignored. But if so, why is this even syntactically correct in the first place?

Comment: Java 10 says `Main.java:5: error: illegal reference to restricted type 'var'
        var<Integer> list = new java.util.ArrayList<Double>();`.

Comment: @ggorlen We originally tried this on Eclipse where this was indeed a perfectly valid program. In response to your comment, I've just tried it with javac and there, this is indeed incorrect.

Comment: @ggorlen AFAIK, it does not, as it uses a custom compiler. Well, at least this works in Eclipse, you may try this yourself if you want. :-)

Comment: @ggorlen: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47623570/869736

Comment: Java 11(?) introduced the concept that you don't need to declare a variable if it's initialised in the same line, ie `List<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Double>();` can now be `var<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Double>();` ... because typing is hard for some people .  This is only available, AFAIK to local variables (ie within a closed context)

Comment: Ah, I see you're right. I don't use Eclipse so I learned something new. I guess I'd edit the post then to mention this is specific to ECJ.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is indeed a bug, but the proof lies in the [Java Language Specification § 14.4 Local Variable Declaration Statements](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se14/html/jls-14.html#jls-LocalVariableType):

> ```
> LocalVariableType:
>     UnannType
>     var
> ```

Ad you can see, the *restricted identifier* `var` is listed without any other token. Also, `UnannType` eventually resolves to the token `TypeIdentifier` which explicitly forbids `var`.

So no, `var<Integer>` is **not** valid.

Answer (score 8):

As it turns out, the usage of `var<T>` is only allowed in Eclipse with JDT core, javac does not accept this. Therefore, I assume this is a bug in Eclipse.

EDIT: As @MC Emperor showed, this is definitely a bug. I have added this bug to the Eclipse Bugzilla.

Comment: Bugzilla entry: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=560999