# My simple Java program runs with no problem on Eclipse, however can't find Java in my pc

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a Windows laptop provided by my employer. I don't have admin rights. I was able to download Eclipse for Java and run a very simple program that printed to the console "hello world". However, I'm not able to find the Java files. I used the cmd command `java -version` and it does not recognize it. I looked in the Local disk > program files, and didn't find Java there either. Can someone explain what is going on?

Comment: It would be a good start to find programmatically where is java installed :) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9006127/find-absolute-java-exe-path-programmatically-from-java-code

Comment: In the run configuration (_Run > Run Configurations..._) there is a button _Show Command Line_. Maybe you do not installed Java on your system, but using the Java that is part of your Eclipse installation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Long story short:
[Eclipse has it's own compiler, it does not use the JDK compiler.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47623117/which-java-compiler-is-used-by-eclipse#:%7E:text=2%20Answers&text=Eclipse%20has%20its%20own%20Java,eclipse.)
So it makes perfect sense that Java is not installed but yet you are able to run the code from Eclipse.

Comment: I see, makes sence. How can I check what version is it using? and would I be able to run more complex code?

Comment: Try to go to eclipse folder and you will see jdk ,java and other files. copy that folder path and run command java -version in a Terminal

Comment: Only found this folder "java-2021-06". I runed from that path the java -version command and still didn't work

Comment: opened it from eclipse terminal. All good. Thanks!

Comment: Sure, Eclipse has its own compiler but a JRE or JDK is needed to run Eclipse (The question was about `java -version`, not `javac -version`). A JDK is required to see the code of system library classes. Some Eclipse IDE packages are shipped with a JDK and in the Eclipse Installer you can choose whether to include Java as part of your Eclipse installation or use a Java installed on your system to run Eclipse.

Comment: I found that it uses an openjdk version 16. is that the same as a regular JDK?

Answer (score 0):

You can only use command "java -version" in console if the windows system variable Path contains the "path" to the folder where java is located.

ie:

```
variable: Path
value: C:\Program Files\Common Files\Oracle\Java\javapath
```

Go to system properties and look for environment variables.

Answer (score 0):

Try to go to eclipse folder and you will see jdk ,java and other files. Copy that java folder path and run command java -version in a Terminal